# Find solutions of $f\left( x,y \right)+f\left( y,x \right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Is it possible to find all functions such that:
$$
f\left( x,y \right)+f\left( y,x \right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}
}$$
In particular $f\left( x,y \right)=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$.  I can't think of any other.

Comment: @logo should be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4xy}}$.

Comment: You can add an arbitrary function $g$ satisfying $g(x, y) = -g(y, x)$.

Comment: Simple example of what everyone else is mentioning.. $$f(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{xy}} + (x-y). $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$g(x,y)=f(x,y)-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$$

Then you have $g(x,y)+g(y,x)=0,$ or $$g(x,y)=-g(y,x).\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, given any $g$ such that $g(x,y)=-g(y,x),$ you could define $$f(x,y)=g(x,y)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$$

Given any $h(x,y)$ you can define $g(x,y)=h(x,y)-h(y,x).$ . This gives all such $g,$ because given a $g(x,y)$ satisfying $(1),$ we can define $h(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}g(x,y)$ and then $$h(x,y)-h(y,x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(g(x,y)-g(y,x)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(g(x,y)+g(x,y)\right)=g(x,y)$$

---

**Full Answer**

So all $f(x,y)$ can be defined by choosing any $h(x,y)$ and defining:

$$f(x,y)=h(x,y)-h(y,x)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}.$$

Two such $h_1,h_2$ give the same $f$ if adn only if $h_3(x,y)=h_1(x,y)-h_2(x,y)$ satisfies $h_3(x,y)=h_3(y,x).$

---

**More generally**

This can be described as a linear functional. Take $V$ as space of all functions of two positive real variables. Then define, for each $h\in V,$ as $(Th)(x,y)=h(y,x).$ Then $T$ is a linear map on $V$, and $T^2=I,$ the identity on $V.$

Then you are seeking solutions to $(T+I)f = \sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}.$

More generally, given $p\in V$, you might try to solve $(T+I)f=p.$ For Applying $T-I$ to botb sides, this would require:

$$0=(T^2-I)f=(T-I)(T+I)f=(T-I)p.$ And $(T-I)p=0$$ is equivalent to $p(x,y)=p(y,x).$ So, to have a solution to $(T+I)f=p,$ you must have $p(x,y)=p(y.x)=(Tp)(x,y).$

And since  $Tp=p$ and thus that $(T+I)(\frac{1}{2}p)=p.$

We also have that if $f$ is a solution, then $f+(T-I)h$ is also a solution, for any $h,$ since $$(T+I)\left(f+(T-I)h\right) = (T+I)f+(T^2-I)h=(T+I)f=p.$$

So, given a linear functional $T\neq I$ on $V,$ with $T^2=I$ and some $p\in V$ such that $Tp=p,$ the general solution to the equation $(T+I)f = p$ exist $\frac{1}{2}p+(T-I)h$ for any $h.$

This works for any $T$ with $T\neq I$ and $T^2=I.$ For example, when $p>0$:

$$(T_ph)(x,y)=\left(py,\frac{1}{p}x\right)$$

has the property that $(T_p-I)\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}=0.$

So the solutions to $f(x,y)+f(py,x/p)=\sqrt{{1}{xy}}$

are of the form $$f=(T_p-I)h + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{{1}{xy}}$$ for any $h.$

This give: $f(x,y)=h(py,x/p)-h(x,y) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{{1}{xy}}.$

Answer (score 1):

For every function:

$f(x, y) = \frac{f(x, y) + f(y, x)}{2} + \frac{f(x, y) - f(y, x)}{2} = u(x, y) + v(x, y)$, where $u(x, y) = u(y, x)$ and $v(x, y) = - v(y, x)$

Hence:

$f(x, y) + f(y, x) = u(x, y) + v(x, y) + u(x, y) - v(x, y) = 2u(x, y) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$

So we get that $u(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}}$

That's why $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}} + v(x, y)$, where $v(x, y) = - v(y, x)$